# Can unused javascript functions slow down page performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

Trying to choose the right theme: I have a main javascript file with an amount of 500kb. In this file are many functions, which are not being used on the current site.

Beside the additional load on page load:
Can these unused functions slow down the performance?

Can unused functions require RAM or CPU usage on visitors end, even if they are not used, for example because they're storing variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what are the consequences of having unused functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958651/what-are-the-consequences-of-having-unused-functions)

Comment: They have to be parsed and stored somewhere; yes, any additional code incurs *some* overhead. *How much* is the question and does it matter vs. incurring development overhead?

Comment: Im pretty sure that if you comment the code out, and use a minimizer, it will remove it for you

Comment: @Sandman thank you for the link!

Comment: @deceze trying to build on wordpress and want to decide between avada (500kb js already minified) and divi (200kb unminified -> 140kb minified). I need to add greensock and on special sites some other special plugins like mixitup or datatables. Some sites also will have some custom js, so the script files will increase. Since many options in avada will be deactivated (shrinking/fixed header etc.) I was wondering if this can harm performance. Otherwhise I would stick to avada, easy-care in my opinion

Comment: A decent build system can possibly [shake those dead functions out automatically](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because these functions are still being downloaded by the browser and stored in memory of the page in the browser.

But mind you, they probably won't have a big effect, so purging the javascript may not lead to a noticable increase, unless your users are visiting the site with a really slow internet connection or something.

Answer (score 3):

> Beside the additional load on page load: Can these unused functions slow down the performance?

*Beside* the additional load on page load? Only if the user is on an extremely memory-starved device. 500k of JavaScript code doesn't translate into much memory usage for the parsed result at all, the effect of it sitting in memory will, in all but the most unusual environments, be effectively zero.

But two points on the thing you were leaving out with that "beside" comment:

- Downloading the unnecessary code; could have a noticeable effect on a slower connection.
- Parsing (and possibly compiling) the unnecessary code; could have a very small effect on the apparent page load, on a device with a really slow processor or a browser with a really slow JavaScript engine.

But effectively, in the vast majority of environments, just having the extra functions around won't cause a noticeable effect at all. It's primarily downloading the unnecessary program text that will be noticeable.

Comment: Crowder
 yes, I had the additional page load in mind. I guess I will stick around of 800-900kb page size on avada and 400-500kb on divi in the end, when I can trust in gtmetrix. Maybe I am also able to defer parsing javascript on page load, where avada automatically hits more points on gtmetrix than divi. I'd like to stick with avada, but I am a little bit afraid of these huge amount of files